# how to generate keystroke combination in win32 api?

Tags: winapi, keyboard, keyboard-events, keycode, keystrokes

i have this code that simulates the pressing of the window key. But how would i make it to press window+d key, essentially showing desktop.

```
void ShowDesktop(void)
{


  // Simulate a key press
     keybd_event( VK_LWIN,
                  0x5B,
                  KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0,
                  0 );

  // Simulate a key release
     keybd_event( VK_LWIN,
                  0x5B,
                  KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,
                  0);

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you must call [`keybd_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the Virtual key value and the hardware scan code for the <kbd>D</kbd> key to get this value you can use the [`MapVirtualKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

try this sample.

```
//simulate the Win key press
    keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0x5B, 0, 0);
//simulate the 'D' key press,the 0x44 is the Virtual key value for the 'D' key, the 0x20 vaue is the hardware scan code for the 'D' key
    keybd_event(0x44, 0x20, 0, 0);
//simulate the 'D' key release
    keybd_event(0x44, 0x20, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
//simulate the Win key release
    keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0x5B, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```